# Rails: Change form submit image on hover using image_submit_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, image

What's the most elegant 'rails' way to implement a hover on an image which submits a form with good cross browser functionality?

For just an image, image_tag works fine:

```
<%= image_tag("mouse.png", :mouseover => "/images/mouse_over.png") %>
```

For image_submit_tag, :mouseover doesn't work.

One way I thought of was to use the html.erb file with css but it has cross browser issues:

```
<%= image_submit_tag "", :class => "icon" %>
```

CSS:

```
.icon { background-image: url('images/mouse.png')}
.icon:hover { background-image: url('images/mouse_over.png')}
```

Outside of rails, one could use javascript or css. What's the most elegant way to do this in rails with image_submit_tag?

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest way I could figure out with image_submit_tag:

```
<%= image_submit_tag "mouse.png", 
:onmouseover => "this.src='assets/mouse_over.png'", 
:onmouseout => "this.src='/assets/mouse.png'"%>
```

image_submit_Tag and image_tag treat the :mouseover option differently. This image_tag:

```
<%= image_tag "mouse.png", :mouseover => "mouse_over.png" %>
```

will take :mouseover option and convert this into:

```
<img src="/assets/mouse.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='/assets/mouse_over.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='/assets/mouse.png'" alt="mouse">
```

But image_submit_tag:

```
<%= image_submit_tag "mouse.png", :mouseover => "mouse_over.png" %>
```

will take the :mouseover option as follows:

```
<input type="image" src="/assets/mouse.png" mouseover="mouse_over.png">
```

Therefore, you must specify onmouseover, onmouseout and the assets directory explicitly when using image_submit_tag.

Answer (score 0):

image_submit_tag generates an  tag with a src attribute.

```
<input type='submit' src='image.png'></input>
```

You can alter that source attribute via javascript.

```
$("input.icon").hover(function(){
   $(this).attr("src", 'images/mouse_over.png');
});
```

Comment: I tried this but when I hover over it, it says the text "Submit Query"